# In the original Sailor Moon intro sequence, why does Luna's brief appearance not show up when she sings "neko"?

Tags: music, anime-production, anime-history, sailor-moon

"Neko" means "cat" in Japanese. That much I know.

I always assumed that they had to change the structure of the song too much in the Swedish translation, due to differences in the languages, and that's the reason why the line:

> ... and got for friend a wonderful cat!

does not show up in the "right" moment, when Luna is for a split second shown on the screen up-close.

But now I've watched and listened to the Japanese original intro enough times to notice that, indeed, the word "neko" appears when the airship is ascending -- not even close to synced to the Luna close-up!

I find this very interesting. Was this a mistake? Did they originally intend to have the word and image match up, but for some reason, didn't think it fit? Why not simply rearrange the pictures so that they better match the lyrics? If I still had Premiere Pro, I would've re-cut it and uploaded just to show that it would've worked...

Here is what I'm talking about: https://youtu.be/LGQCPOMcYJQ?t=43

A few seconds in, you see the Luna close-up shot, then it goes to the airship sequence, and only *then* does the singer mention "neko". All logic dictates that Luna should show up at the mention of "neko"!

Comment: Just as the answer says, I fail to see any reference to "cat" (ねこ, 猫, *neko*) in the video. Did you perhaps mishear 万**華鏡** (ま**んげきょう**, ma***ngekyo***)?

Answer (score 4):

> "Neko" means "cat" in Japanese.

Absolutely correct!

> the word "neko" appears when the airship is ascending

> and only then does the singer mention "neko"

Sorry, there is no word "neko" in the Japanese lyrics of this song.

> Was this a mistake? Did they originally intend to have it mach up, but for some reason didn't think it fit? Why not simply rearrange the pictures so that they better match the lyrics?

Luna shows up in sync when the drummer hits the toms (dududum sound), in superb precision!

Comment: It might be worth quoting the Japanese lyrics of the song (or at least, that specific line) just to back up your point about them not containing the word "neko".